# Is there a way to force the iOS Simulator to start in landscape mode, when launching the simulator outside of XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator

I know that within your application code and your app.plist file that you can set orientation settings for an application but I am not interested in that information.  I'm well aware of it and I've used it for my needs many times.

What I would like is for the iOS Simulator to start in Left-Home-Landscape mode when it "boot's up" before it runs my application.  If my application defaults to portrait mode, the iOS simulator should start up in landscape and then my application should auto-rotate to portrait.

I am aware that I could start the simulator and then manually rotate the device from the iOS Simulator Hardware menu, but I'd rather not have to do it that way if I can get around it.

Is their an iOS Simulator setting that is buried some where that can do this?  I would imagine that this isn't most-likely possible because when you boot up an iOS device, it always starts out first in portrait mode.  I'm hoping, however, that's not the exact case for the simulator.

**MORE INFORMATION**

FYI, this is for XCode <strike>4.3.1</strike> 4.3.2 and as I mentioned in comments below, assume that I'm starting the simulator without pre-loading a project by debugging it in XCode.  If I just launch the simulator, I want it to startup in landscape.

Comment: I think there's something you can put in info.plist, but I don't remember what so this is only a comment and not an Answer.

Comment: Thanks, but yes, I am aware of that.  Consider it like this, if I was to start the simulator app, without launching an associated process, is there a way to configure the sim so that it would automatically start in landscape, independent of an iOS project.  If there is an info.plist file associated with the simulator, where might I find it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the simulator plist, I've noticed that if the app crashes in landscape orientation in the simulator, the next time you run it, it starts out in landscape orientation.

So you could assign some temporary action to a button or whatever that accesses a released object, causing a crash. Run the app in the simulator, rotate it to landscape, and then tap the button to crash it. Stop the app. Next time you run it, it will be in landscape orientation.

Very ugly, but it's quick and it will probably work.

---

Sorry, I just tested it and there are a couple caveats:

1) The crash has to happen in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation. That is, rotating to landscape has to trigger the crash. Which makes this kludge *really* ugly.

2) I didn't see your added info when I posted this answer: It won't work if you quit out of the simulator program itself following the crash. You have to just stop your *app* following the crash and relaunch it.

Comment: Wow, I'll keep that in mind.  I've found the simulator app, which i buried within the xcode.app file, and it's associated info.plist.  However, there is no added property within the plist for the start-up orientation.  It may be an optional property, but I haven't been brave enough to try and guess what that might be and where it belongs.

Comment: All that's happening here is that the simulator is continuing to run. "windowOrientation" does change when the simulated device rotates, but it doesn't get processed at startup as far as I can tell.  File a bug.